# How can I correct an "Invalid face" error?

Tags: org-mode, faces, themes

Issuing `M-x org-html-htmlize-generate-css` gives the error

```
Invalid face: font-lock-string
```

What does this error mean and how can I correct it?

Issuing `$ grep -r "font-lock-string[^-]" ~/.emacs.d/` returns

```
~/.emacs.d/elpa/solarized-theme-20160106.15/solarized.el: `(kite-string((,class (:inherit font-lock-string))))
```

Comment: I don't know, but forcing it to print the stack trace might help to investigate. To get the stack trace do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`.

Comment: I guess you have a source block in your org-file and this source code block uses some wired programming major mode. Try to open a file with that major mode. Does this work or do you get the same error message? **Please** give a minimal example for error reconstruction. Try with `emacs -Q` only loading the modes you really need for the reconstruction of the problem.

Comment: Beyond turning on `debug-on-error` (@wvxvw's good suggestion), you can follow the evaluation to see exactly what goes wrong, by: (1) loading the source file that defines function `org-html-htmlize-generate-css`, (2) `M-x debug-on-entry RET org-html-htmlize-generate-css`, (3) use `d` to step through the evaluation (or `c` sometimes, to skip through uninteresting parts). Keep the source code open in another frame, so you can follow better.

Comment: You can also check what the current definition of `font-lock-string` is, using `M-x customize-face RET font-lock-string RET`. If it says `mismatch` then look for what is wrong, or try customizing it again, starting with the original value.

Comment: @Dew When I try completion with `M-x customize-face` on `font-lock-string` I only get `font-lock-string-face` that makes me suspicious that there is some source code block in the OP's org file with a major mode that wrongly uses `font-lock-string` instead of `font-lock-string-face`.

Comment: @Tobias Trying completion with `M-x customize-face` on `font-lock-string` also only gives `font-lock-string-face`.

Comment: Yes I think this is the culpright. If you have the lisp sources (not only the elc-files) you could grep these sources for the regular expression `font-lock-string[^-]`. The wrong face symbol could also be in `~/.emacs` or in your customization/configuration files under `~/.emacs.d/`.

Comment: @Tobias Issuing `$ grep -r "fond-lock-string[^-]" .` while in `~/.emacs.d/` returns `./elpa/solarized-theme-20160106.15/solarized.el:     \`(kite-string ((,class (:inherit font-lock-string))))`

Comment: Also, I am using the solarized theme.

Comment: These are faces (as https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs/blob/master/solarized.el shows). Change it to `font-lock-string-face` and try again. If you are lucky you got the culprit else maybe, you got to go on with your search.

Comment: `change-log-file` is really a face. It is defined in library `add-log`. You need `(require 'add-log)` before loading `solarized.el`.

Comment: Now I'm getting `Invalid face: ecb-default-general-face`. Should I have something like `(require 'ecb)`?

Comment: You could try `(defadvice org-add-props (before check-faces activate)
  "Check face properties whether they really define faces."
  (let ((plist-face (plist-get plist 'face))
 (props-face (plist-get props 'face)))
    (when (and plist-face (null (facep plist-face)))
      (cl-remf plist 'face))
    (when (and props-face (null (facep props-face)))
      (cl-remf props 'face))))` to avoid error messages. Hopefully, it runs with org 8.3.2. Don't know whether it cures all problems. But, actually, one should fix `solarized`. Regarding `ecb` just try yourself.

Comment: Please report a bug for that theme.  This is not something you should work around yourself.

Comment: @wasamasa I'm not quite sure how to do that. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs/issues/new

Comment: In case someone sees similar error for PHP code, it may helpful to check https://github.com/ejmr/php-mode/pull/212/files which provided a fix for php-mode.